# Why grad_output requires_grad is False in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

Here is the [customLayer.py](https://gist.github.com/Naruto-Sasuke/8a1400382c1a9c0785ad09853d711c8c).

I am quite confused about the following things:

1. The input of the inner layer is not a Variable. Then in `backward` it becomes a Variable and requires gradient. Why?
2. `grad_output` is a Variable yet requires_grad is False. Why is not true?
3. In my custom layer, I need customize forward and backward operations. It is quite complicated. See the same link. I have posted questions in it.

Comment: 1. what do you mean by inner layer?
2. grad_output, as the name says is the result of gradient calculation. why should this variable require_grad?

Answer (score 1):

1. The gradients are updated through your loss computation and are required for the backpropagation. If you don't have gradients, you cant train your network.
2. Probably, because you don't want the gradients last on the variable. It's temporally only for one backward phase.
3. Why do you need a custom backward function? Do you need extra operations on your backpropagation?